# Setup for hosting websites

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have a website and a web service created in asp.net and c#. They work without any problems, and I have been using by deploying in the IIS, bu I have been doing this maually. Now, I want to minimize the number of steps, by creating a setup, which would automatically add my webservice and website in the iis, without the user having to do it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There should be a deploy feature in Visual Studio. Actually it is "Publish" that should publish the websites and webservices pretty much automatically.

Comment: No actually I have the published files, and instead of going to the iis and adding applications, I want to automate this process of deploying the website.

Comment: It would help, if anyone could let me know how to create custom setups, because I did some research and wrote a code to host applications in the IIS. Hence, if there is some way that I can make my code run through the setup, even that would help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MSBuild](http://codingcockerel.co.uk/2008/05/18/how-to-publish-a-web-site-with-msbuild/) to automate your builds. 
On top of this you can use [Albacore](https://github.com/derickbailey/Albacore).

As an alternative you can use [Nant](http://nant.sourceforge.net/).